# How to add link to only last data with simple_fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to add `link_to_remove` to **only** last data.

The following code has `link_to_remove` for all data.

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :tests do |t| %>
  ...
  <%= t.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
<% end %>
```

My image is to use `last?` such as

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :tests do |t| %>
  ...
  <% if t.last? %>
    <%= t.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show the `forms_for` that appears before the `simple_fields_for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the test object is the last test of the parent object

```
f.simple_fields_for :test do |t|
  # ...
  t.link_to_remove("Remove") if t.object == f.object.tests.last
end
```

Comment: Spot on, you want to use `t.object` as `t` is the formbuilder instance - not the actual wrapped model instance.